# How to change input field with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, input

could someone explain me please, how to change the input field of this site with JQUERY or JAVASCRIPT?

I want to change the input field, where **"United States – English"** is written as default value. **I know how to change the other input fields**, but i have problems with this one.

[LINK TO WEBSITE](https://serps.com/tools/rank-checker)

(I want to change it to Germany - German)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want to change it to and when?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question

Comment: Please don't edit your answer like this. If it's no longer relevant then just delete it

Answer (score 0):

`$("#locale-input select").val("Germany - German");`

From jquery docs:

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JQuery val() function.
This should work:

```
$("#locale-input").val("Germany - German");
```